# Every convergent sequence $(x_n)$ is bounded in $(M,d)$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, metric-spaces

I wanted to know if my approach is feasible, and if it is, if I am on the right path.

Suppose $(x_n)$ is unbounded and converges to $x$. From the definition of a limit in a metric space, I gather that $x_n \rightarrow x \implies d(x_n, x) \rightarrow 0$, and that $d(x_n, x) < \epsilon$, for $n \ge N$, where $\epsilon > 0$ and $N \in \mathbb{N}$. The definition of an unbounded sequence, if I remember correctly, is that $\forall k > 0 \ \ \exists \ \ x \in (x_n)$ s.t. $|x| > k$. So if we let $\epsilon = k$ then $|x_n - x| < k \implies x_n < k + x$, a contradiction to $(x_n)$ being unbounded. 
I would appreciate hints as to how to tackle the proof, rather than answers. Thank you.

Comment: What is $M$ and what is $d$?. There is no such thing as $|x|$ for an element $x$ of a general metric space.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I don't I have it specified in my notes. It's just "Properties of limits in Metric Spaces"

Comment: In that case you have to assume that $(M,d)$ is a general metric space. There is no absolute value and there are no inequalities in a general metric space, so your answer is wrong. A set in a general metric space. is bounded if it is contained in some open ball $B(x,r)$. Try to re-write the proof using this definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your intuition is correct to an extent, but recall that metric spaces are a very general concept. In particular, there is no such thing as an absolute value, or even a distinguished point (as is $0$ for the reals). So,

> *Definition*. A subset $S$ of a metric space $(M,d)$ is **bounded** if there exists a real constant $K > 0$ such that $d(s,s') < K$ for any $s,s' \in S$.

In other terms, $S$ is bounded if its **diameter**, $\operatorname{diam}(M) := \sup\{d(s,s') : s,s' \in S\}$ is finite.

> *Definition*. A sequence $(x_n)_{n \geq 1} \subset (M,d)$ is bounded if $\{x_n\}_{n \geq 1}$ is bounded in $M$.

That is, a sequence is bounded if its terms, as a subset of $M$, are bounded in the 'metric' sense given in the previous definition.

Now, extend your intuition to a general case, but adjusting your tools to this context. A possible (direct) solution follows.

> *Proposition*. Let $(x_n)_{n \geq 1}$ be a convergent sequence on a metric space $(M,d)$. Then, the sequence $(x_n)_{n \geq 1}$ is bounded.

*Proof*. Since the sequences converges, writing $l := \lim_{n \to \infty}x_n$, there exists $n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n \geq n_0$ implies $d(x_n,l) < 1$. Thus, if $K := \max\{d(x_i,l): 1 \leq i\leq n_0\}$,

$$
d(x_n,x_m) \leq d(x_n,l) + d(l,x_m) \leq 2(K+1)
$$

because $d(x_k,l) \leq K+1$ for any $k$, by construction of $K$ and $n_0$. Thus, the sequence has finite finite diameter. $\square$

Comment: Thank you sir, this is the proof that we went over class and it made a lot of sense, I guess I was wondering why we couldn't use a contradiction to try and prove it. I suppose I should brush up on the exact definition of a metric space. I suppose I confused the 4 properties of a metric function as the definition of the space itself.

Comment: @zodross I haven't tried it myself, but I think your proof via contrapositive can be adapted just fine: suppose the sequence unbounded so that for each $k$ there exists $x_{n_k}, x_{m_k}$ with

$$
1 \leq k \leq d(x_{m_k},x_{n_k}) \leq d(x_{m_k},l) + d(l,x_{n_k}) 
$$

Take limits (remember, we are now in $\mathbb{R}$ since that is the codomain of $d$), we get from the very left and the very right that $1 \leq 0$, so we reach a contradiction.

You should justify why we can take $m_k,n_k$ increasing so that they form a subsequence (and thus converge to $l$).

Comment: Thank you kindly.

Comment: No problem! Please read the last line of my comment, there is a subtlety to be taken care of. Other than that, this should work :)

Comment: If a sequence $(x_n)$ converges to $l$, then any subsequence $(x_(n_k))$ of $(x_n)$ also converges to $l$. $\therefore$, we can find such subsequences $m_k, n_k$?

Comment: Yes, although you should think about why we can. Suppose that we cannot take such $m_k, n_k$ increasing. Then the indices whose terms are far apart are bounded, contradicting that the sequence is unbounded.

Comment: Ohhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh. That's so cool! Thank you so much!

Comment: Glad I could help :)